# Binding values with list matching (without compiler warning)

Tags: f#

Let's say I have a function that takes some `int` parameters, but inside which I will use `float32`.

I'd prefer not to use the `float32 i` function everywhere.

Instead, I want to do this:

```
let x = float32 x
let y = float32 y
let w = float32 w
let h = float32 h
```

To tighten it up a bit, I could do this:

```
let x, y, w, h = float32 x, float32 y, float32 w, float32 h
```

I'd like to do this:

```
let [x;y;w;h] = List.map float32 [x;y;w;h]
```

This works, but I get a compiler warning of `Incomplete pattern matching on this expression`, because there is no static check that the rhs will have exactly 4 items (could be empty, could have 1 item, could have a thousand).

I don't want to disable the compiler warning.
Is this just a bad idea? Should I ignore the compiler warning in this one case, or is there some nice, idiomatic way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a map function specifically for 4-tuples:

```
let map4 f (x, y, w, h) = (f x, f y, f w, f h)
```

It has the type `f:('a -> 'b) -> x:'a * y:'a * w:'a * h:'a -> 'b * 'b * 'b * 'b`. Notice that all the elements in the tuple are assumed to have the same type.

Sample usage (FSI):

```
> let x, y, w, h = map4 float32 (1, 2, 3, 4);;

val y : float32 = 2.0f
val x : float32 = 1.0f
val w : float32 = 3.0f
val h : float32 = 4.0f
```

I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to implement `map2`, `map3`, etc. ;)

Comment: Thanks, Mark! I ended up making `List.toTuple2` … `List.toTuple5` so mapping is not intrinsic. `let [x;y;w;h;f1] = [x;y;w;h;1] |> List.map float32 |> List.toTuple5`.

Comment: @Jay What happens for `[x;y] |> List.map float32 |> List.toTuple5`?

Comment: I was hoping nobody would ask me that.

Answer (score 0):

The incomplete pattern warning is because there is a case that you forgot: the case of the empty list [].

Are you obligate to use x,y,z ... ? 
This is work :  `let l = List.map float32 [x;y;w;h]` without warning.

Comment: The whole point is to bind `x` `y` `w` `h` in order to use the values within the body of the containing function. I don't need the list, I need the mapped values.

Comment: Why did you not use a record ?

Comment: The parameters are fixed by Android interfaces. I could delegate to my own function that takes the record, but wouldn't gain much by doing so.